# Does a Dwelf, Dwarf / Elf hybrid ever appear in any Fantasy, besides D&D?

Tags: elves, dwarves

In the *Dungeons and Dragons* role-playing games there exists the Dwelf, which is a hybrid between Dwarf and Elf.

*The Hobbit* movie franchise shows a romance between the dwarf Kili and the elf Tauriel.
I wasn't particularly impressed by that addition by Mr. Jackson but it made me wonder.

Is there any fantasy book/movie/story (besides the D&D franchise or material derived from that) that has an actual Dwelf in it?
I can't recall having ever seen one.

Half-dwarves and half-elves are common enough (with the other half being human), but Dwelfs seem to be an exceptionally rare breed.

Comment: http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Half-dwarf

Comment: This question does not ask for a list of all works, but rather if it exists _at all_ outside of D&D. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @SQB Just 1 or 2 examples would satisfy me. I just never encountered one single example myself.

Comment: @Valorum I never got into Forgotten Realms. Seems they are pretty common there.

Comment: @SQB - There's an example [right here](http://pastebin.com/sQnVUN7J). So yes, it does exist.

Comment: *Forgotten Realms* is of course part of *Dungeons & Dragons*.

Comment: This is probably not what you're looking for, but in The Elder Scrolls games, dwarves are a subspecies of elf. A dwarf/elf hybrid would be easily possible, except that the dwarves are apparently extinct.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/InterspeciesRomance/Literature lists a few examples such as *Garrett P.I.* and *War Gods*.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I actually have read the entire War Gods series 1 month before posting the question and completely missed the Elf & Dwarf connection (It is very briefly mentioned when Wencit explains the history of magic and the origin of species). Make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Tonny: Done. I've never read the books myself,but that's what I found via Google. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One 1999 Fantasy example would be David Weber's *[War God](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40512-war-god)* series. All five races of men (humans, elves, dwarves, halflings, and Hradani, can interbreed, although most hybrids are sterile. The TVTropes article on [Interspecies Romance](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/InterspeciesRomance/Literature) notes that elf-dwarf hybrids exist but that they're not well-off and *[The War God's Own](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/119227.The_War_God_s_Own)* has Wencit explaining, "Of course, there could be problems. For example, crosses between darves and elves tend to be very short-lived...".

Comment: As promised....

Answer (score 2):

They are featured in the sci-fi novel, [Wyrms (1987)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wyrms_(novel)) by Orson Scott Card. They are one of three intelligent species that inhabit the planet Imakulata, not including the humans. While not really totally in the fantasy realm, there are obvious D&D elements and influences in this story.

Comment: While called Dwelf, these are not Elf/Dwarf hybrids in the book.